# Slim 4 Framework: Unable to pass a payload to test a POST route

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I'm totally new to Slim 4 but I've successfully managed to create a project and write API endpoint that does some calculation.

[image]

It's a `POST` route and it requires a JSON payload. In Postman I send a `POST` to `http://localhost:8089/api/discounts/calculate` with:

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": "1",
        "customer-id": "1",
        "items": [
            {
                "product-id": "B102",
                "quantity": "10",
                "unit-price": "4.99",
                "total": "49.90"
            }
        ],
        "total": "49.90"
    },
    "discount_strategy": "overall_percentage_from_total"
}
```

and in a response I get `HTTP 200 OK` which is what I expect. Everything works perfectly fine, but not in PHPUnit.

I want to create a test for this endpoint so I've created new test class that extends `TestCase` and it has access to this protected method: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php#L71

So I wrote:

```
public function testOrder1AgainstOverallPercentageFromTotal()
{
    $app = $this->getAppInstance();

    $payload = [
        'order' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'customer-id' => 1,
            'items' => [
                'product-id' => 'B102',
                'quantity' => '10',
                'unit-price' => '4.99',
                'total' => '49.90',
            ],
            'total' => '49.90',
        ],
        'discount_strategy' => 'overall_percentage_from_total',
    ];

    $req = $this->createRequest('POST', '/api/discounts/calculate');
    $request = $req->withParsedBody($payload);

    $response = $app->handle($request);

    //var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents()); die;

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

but it always gives me HTTP 400 saying that:

> Malformed JSON input

When I dump `getBody()` or `getContents()` I get either a hollow object or or empty string for contents.

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Functional\CalculateDiscountsActionTest::testOrder1AgainstOverallPercentageFromTotal
Failed asserting that 400 matches expected 200.
```

What am I doing wrong?

My calculation logic is in an Action class that extents `App\Application\Actions\Action` and I'm able to access the payload I send in Postman with: `$input = $this->getFormData();`. This is a `stdClass` but it's enough for me to grab the input and do the job.

Why PHPUnit doesn't see my payload?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the correct HTTP headers and body content to the request object.

```php
$request->getBody()->write((string)json_encode($data));

$request = $request->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Full example:

```php
protected function createJsonRequest(string $method, $uri, array $data = null): ServerRequestInterface
{
    $request = $this->createRequest($method, $uri);

    if ($data !== null) {
        $request->getBody()->write((string)json_encode($data));
    }

    return $request->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Usage:

```php
$payload = [];

$request = $this->createJsonRequest('POST', '/api/discounts/calculate', $payload);

$response = $app->handle($request);

// Assert the response
// ...
```

[More examples](https://github.com/odan/slim4-skeleton/blob/master/tests/TestCase/Action/User/UserCreateActionTest.php#L31-L50)